# I am trying to change my device's Mac address from adb shell but

Tags: adb

I tried to change the Mac address of my non-rooted Samsung Galaxy J5 2016 (running Android 7.1.1) from adb shell.

But the command 
`ip link set wlan0` [...........]

returns

permission denied.

Any idea out there on how to go around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Permission denied  error because you don't have sufficient privilege to execute that command. You need to elevate them and that can happen if only you root the device or use an exploit that grants you the required privilege.

Find out how to root that device, root it if you can, and then use that command.

Comment: ♦ many thanks for your answer.

Let us say that I'm making my last attempts before rooting my phone.

What exploit could I try to gain the adequate privilege?

Comment: I haven't used any exploits for long and Android's implementation of security has made it hard for people to find or execute exploits successfully to get root privileges. Some apps such as Kingoroot claims to work for certain Android devices but they are very fishy in nature (known for installing backdoors and tracking apps). It would be best if you find how to simply root the device. If it involves an exploit you would get to know it. :)